# MVC 5 IIS not authorized user custom page display

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I got below code in global.asax that is showing error msg when user is not authorized:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Clear();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        context.Response.Write("You are not authorized.");
    }
}
```

In RouteConfig.cs file I got two routes definitions - angular and test:

```
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Test",
                "test/{controller}/{action}"
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "angular",
                    url: "{*.}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
}
```

I'm using angular routing - ui router component.

Instead of displaying message about user not being authorized I want to redirect user to angular route/state "not-autorized", how can I achieve this?

Something like below wont work:

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("not-autorized");
```

Also when I try to redirect to existing angular route like this:

```
context.Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("angular");
```

I'm getting error "This page can't be displayed".

When I added as below:

```
context.Response.RedirectLocation = "/Home/Index";
```

then I'm getting: [401 unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsheF.jpg)

This, post turned to the my monologue, what I found that after getting windows authentication popup and not entering valid credentials Application_EndRequest is no longer triggered so the redirect won't work, what to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a custom authorisation attribute, see below.

```
public class IsAuthenticated : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/AccessDenied");
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that an authenticated user will go to your angular routing page and the others will route to access denied.

Then use the attribute on each controller that you would like to authenticate. E.g:

```
[IsAuthenticated]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now you need to set up a route for your access denied page:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AccessDenied",
        url: "AccessDenied",
        defaults: new { controller = "AccessDenied", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
                url: "{*.}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

This needs to be above the default 'angular' route so it actually can be triggered.

Just to be safe on your AccessDenied controller set the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccessDeniedController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now you are free to create your AccessDenied page.